# JUnit Testing in Multithread Application

Tags: unit-testing, multithreading

This is a problem me and my team faces in almost all of the projects. Testing certain parts of the application with JUnit is not easy and you need to start early and to stick to it, but that's not the question I'm asking. The actual problem is that with n-Threads, locking, possible exceptions within the threads and shared objects the task of testing is not as simple as testing the class, but testing them under endless possible situations within threading.

To be more precise, let me tell you about the design of one of our applications:

When a user makes a request several threads are started that each analyse a part of the data to complete the analysis, these threads run a certain time depending on the size of the chunk of data (which are endless and of uncertain quality) to analyse, or they may fail if the data was insufficient/lacking quality. After each completed its analysis they call upon a handler which decides after each thread terminates if the collected analysis-data is sufficient to deliver an answer to the request.

All of these analysers share certain parts of the applications (some parts because the instances are very big and only a certain number can be loaded into memory and those instances are reusable, some parts because they have a standing connection, where connecting takes time, ex.gr. sql connections) so locking is very common (done with reentrant-locks). While the applications runs very efficient and fast, it's not very easy to test it under real-world conditions.

What we do right now is test each class and it's predefined conditions, but there are no automated tests for interlocking and synchronization, which in my opionion is not very good for quality insurances.

Given this example how would you handle testing the threading, interlocking and synchronization?

Comment: keyword you are looking for is mocking, essentially you immitate the analysation part without doing the analysis, and test the analysers separately, but testing thread safety is a very hard problem in general and no prefab solutions are available

Comment: @ratchetfreak thank you for the mocking reference, that will help in testing, but it seems to be every other week that we encounter a new threading problem (we are in an alpha stage, soon to be beta), which is not very suprising in an applications which is highly optimized to run on an indefinit number of cores, but it's still annoying...

Comment: Don't share mutable state

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since I was never really happy with the answers I received I had already given up and solved the concurrency issues with time but without having actual tests that proved that they were not existing any more. But today I stumbled upon a solution for the problem.

Links that explain writing those kind of tests:

- https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Multithreaded-code-and-concurrency
- http://tempusfugitlibrary.org/recipes/2012/05/20/testing-concurrent-code/
- http://www.planetgeek.ch/2009/08/25/how-to-find-a-concurrency-bug-with-java/

In short all these tests initialize Runnable and start them at exactly the same time to achieve a maximum concurrency-load, this way concurrency issues should be exposed.

Comment: Please note that these tests won't *prove* your concurrency issues don't exist anymore. They simply exercise your threads more, and therefore increase the *chance* of finding concurrency problems if they are there; but I'm afraid this is still no guarantee. Finding and troubleshooting concurrency problems is unfortunately very hard.

Comment: @AndresF. noted and agreed. But running these tests thousands of times will seriously increase the chances of catching concurrency problems. In the end long time field tests are the ink real solution to these kinds of problems. Next time around I hope better planing will solve these problems before they start to exist.

Answer (score 5):

**Sounds like you're doing integration testing not unit testing**

In general, when you unit test you split the code into its smallest parts and test each one in isolation. Sometimes, you need to emulate dependencies - a process called mocking. Good mocking libraries include JMockit (for mocking absolutely anything including making String mutable) or Mockito if your needs are normal.

These days multithreaded applications in Java should be built upon the `java.util.concurrent` packages and have `ExecutorService` at their heart. Unless your needs are very specific there is no real requirement to access `Thread` directly any more.

Given a design based on the concurrency packages you should be able to decompose your analysis and construct isolated unit tests for them. This approach should greatly simplify your code, and make the behaviour of threads a lot more predictable than it currently sounds.

Comment: JUnit is not only used for unit testing, but also for integration testing. It's very hard to unit test concurrency problems, and the OP doesn't seem to be asking about *unit* testing, but about automated (integration) testing.